# How to Call a function inside an array value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Actually I need to call a function inside an array value.

this my function

```
public function RelationName()
    {
        return $this->name .'--'. $this->relationship;
    }
```

I need to call this above function in another function which present same class file

this is my another function:

```
public static function getClaimerNameList($cat_id, $subcat_id)
    {
        $out = [];

        $emp_code = Employee::find()
                ->where(['importcompany_id' => $cat_id])
                ->andWhere(['id' => $subcat_id])
                ->all();

        foreach ($emp_code as $dat => $datas) {
            $out[] = ['id' => $datas['id'], 'name' => $datas['name'] ];

            if($dat == 0){
                    $aux = $datas['id'];
                }

            ($datas['id'] == $subcat_id) ? $selected = $subcat_id : $selected = $aux;

        }
        return $output = [
            'output' => $out,
            'selected' => $selected
        ];
    }
```

Actually I need to call function here

```
foreach ($emp_code as $dat => $datas) {
                $out[] = ['id' => $datas['id'], 'name' => $datas['name'] ];
}
```

`instead 'name' => $datas['name']` of this, I need to call a function `getRelationName()`

without using function am getting output like

```
id name
1  raja
2  ram
```

but I don't wanna output like that, if I use a function I will get output like below

```
id name
1   raja-father
2   ram-son
```

Help me to sort out this problem

Comment: you mean ... $name=RelationName(); $out[] = ['id' => $datas['id'], 'name' => $name ];

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that but am getting error

Comment: post your attempt and mention error details

Comment: getting this error **Call to undefined function RelationName**

Comment: if i use like this $name = $this->RelationName(), then am getting error as **Using $this when not in object context&#039**

Comment: I would suggest , if you can use `$dat` or `$datas` or something like that as argument of `RelationName()` so that it will be called for every element in the array then you can call the function just before ` $out[] = ['id' => $datas['id'], 'name' => $datas['name'] ];` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this

```
foreach ($emp_code as $dat => $datas) 
{
  $out[] = ['id' => $datas['id'], 'name' => $datas->RelationName() ];

  //more code...
}
```

And `RelationName()` need to be located in the `Employee` class and it shouldn't be static

Comment: Am geting this Error **<pre>PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Using $this when not in object context&#039;**

Comment: Notice it's **not** `$this->RelationName()` but `$datas->RelationName()`. Also, you sure `RelationName()` is defined in `Employee`?

Comment: i used in $datas->RelationName() only and am defined in employee only but still am getting error

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your RelationName() function isn't declared as static? It isn't in your question, but the kind of error points that way.

Comment: Well, thats the problem, it shouldn't be static.

Comment: Can you link me to a pastebin of your Employee class?

Comment: Thanks. Where's the RelationName() function?